# Get another components context in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5.

I have two components/folders with views & controllers named 'view' and 'tableview'. Is it possible get 'view' context in 'tableview'  ?

Comment: what do you mean by View context?Or do you mean View controller in MVC world?

Comment: i have multiple views.xml & controller.js files in a folder named 'view'. same way I have multiple views.xml & controller.js in a folder named 'tableview'. Now, I am loading a view(child) from 'tableview' folder with in a view(parent) which is in 'view' folder. I am wondering if there is any way for child to access parents context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are trying to access a parent controller from a child controller. Here are some proposals ordered from noob to expert ;)

1. The simplest approach would be to just use a global variable to provide reference to the controller you need - not recommended.
2. Give your parent view an id and call a method on it's controller like this:

   sap.ui.getCore().byId("parentViewId").getController().method();
3. You can directly call a controllers method like this:

   sap.ui.controller("namespace.Controllername").method();
4. I would highly recommend a more decoupled way of communication between controllers (or application components in general) using the [sap.ui.core.EventBus](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.EventBus.html). It implements a pattern known as Event or Message Bus and imho really rocks ;)

GL
Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris. I was able to call parentview's method using sap.ui.controller("namespace.Controllername").method(); .....Is there a possibility to access parent controller's context or 'this' object in child controller ?

Comment: sap.ui.controller("namespace.Controllername") gives you what you call the parent controllers context. you could also get properties from it if you like. still sth missing?